# Where in the PHB is the information on the different regions dwarves come from?

Tags: dnd-4e, content-identification

I thought I saw somewhere in the 4e Player's Handbook the different regions the dwarves live in, but now I can't find it. (I would like to use a dice to randomly select my region to help build my backstory/personality.) What page is it on? If I'm remembering wrong and it's not in the PHB, where is it?

Comment: I'm voting to close as unclear until you've specified which 4e setting your group is using: default (the one in the PHB/DMG/anything which doesn't specify otherwise, unofficially called 'Points of Light'), Dark Sun, Eberron, Forgotten Realms...?

Answer (score 1):

As @ObliviousSage stated in comments, there is very little actual geography in the 4e PHB, since the "Points of Light" setting that is the default for 4e has very little content, and is largely just intended to simply set a general tone so GMs can put whatever they want in it.However, 4e also has campaign setting books for Dark Sun, Forgotten Realms, and Eberron. Those books would definitely have information on dwarven culture and where dwarves are found in that setting.